# How to make GoogleBot recognize embedded object in HTML?

Tags: html, object

```
<object width="900" height="900" data="https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://example.com/mydoc.pdf"></object>
```

I embed PDF on my site using the above code. The GoogleBot does not "see" the pdf embedded. The page has no other visual content on it except a link to download the same PDF. I want the bot to read the PDF and want the page to show up in SERP.
Will it work? If not, what are the options?

Comment: I edited your title because the terms "good" and "SEO" tend to trigger downvoting and closing as off-topic. I hope it brings out the technical aspect of your problem.